# Heroku Hosting Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I host with company X and have my domain on there. I deployed my app to heroku and pointed my domain at it. I can't wrap my head around if I am hosting my site on heroku now or if I am hosting it on company X's servers.

I would assume I'm hosting on herokus server because that is the most logical, but just keep having this brainfart.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is on Heroku's server. All company X has done is perform the DNS magic necessary to map the friendly URL (www.yoursite.com) to your Heroku deployment.

Comment: For some reason its reassuring hearing that from someone else.

Comment: I'm glad you feel better. Too bad you couldn't also get the effect of my soothing voice.

Answer (score 0):

**Amazon**

You should also be aware that Heroku doesn't actually "store" the app on its own servers - [it uses Amazon's `ec2` cloud](http://www.quora.com/Heroku/Where-are-Heroku-apps-hosted) to create `instances` of your app

So although you have your domain with company X, your app handled through `heroku`, it will actually be running in one of Amazon's data centers

Keep that in mind when you start to grow (you may find benefits of using Amazon directly)